# Soap Package in Go

Tags: web-services, soap, go

I am searching a package for soap call in Go but not able to find one. Though i have find
[MFenniak Soap Work](https://github.com/mfenniak/go-soap) and [Webconnex soap work](https://github.com/webconnex/xmlutil)
but these are specific to their needs so i am not able to make them my base point and start working on them. Is there any generic soap library like  [gSOAP for C/C++](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)in Go. In Go we could use c code. So is it wise  to use C-gsoap code in Go?

Comment: @Anonymous I have look that code and it is none other than [https://github.com/webconnex/xmlutil] explanation which i have already mentioned in my question

Comment: @Anonymous i also want to know if some one has used c gsoap in by importing c in golang

Comment: @user2383973, unfortunately, in this case your question, again, has to be closed but with "Too broad" or "Primarily opinion-based" reason: please understand that SO is not about asking "did someone use X?" or "can I use Y to solve X?" -- instead, it's about asking for help with *concrete* problems, such as where you can provide a minimal code example, state how you want it to work and ask why it doesn't -- something like this.

Comment: @user2383973, IOW if you failed to find Go bindings for `gSOAP` written by someone else it's pointless to ask on SO whether it's okay to create such bindings -- it's pointless because you cannot say without attempting to do that.

Comment: @user2383973, From my recent personal experience when I needed to do SOAP calls from a Delphi 7 (yes, that old) application, and discovered all 4 available solutions suck big time in different ways I've created a simple package which did simple SOAP parsing and simple encoding. By being *not* too generic it did the job just okay: monstrosity of SOAP libraries is due to them being too generic. If you don't need to auto-generate (de-)serialization code from WSDLs and are fine to hand-write it using simple helper routines then everything needed is already available in Go.